# Create hub module from existing checkpoint

Tags: python, python-3.x, tensorflow, tensorflow-serving, tensorflow-hub

Is it possible to create a `hub` module from existing checkpoints without chaining the training code?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, absolutely. You need a session with (1) a Module and (2) the proper values in its variables. It doesn't matter if those come from actual training or merely restoring a checkpoint. Given a Python library for model building that knows nothing about TensorFlow Hub, you can have a tool on the side for export to a Hub Module that looks like:

```
import tensorflow_hub as hub
import your_library as build_model_body

def module_fn():
  inputs = tf.placeholder(...)
  logits = build_model_body(inputs)
  hub.add_signature(inputs=inputs, outputs=logits)

def main(_):
  spec = hub.create_module_spec(module_fn)
  # Supply a checkpoint trained on a model from the same Python code.
  checkpoint_path = "..."
  # Output will be written here:
  export_path = "..."
  with tf.Graph().as_default():
    module = hub.Module(spec)
    init_fn = tf.contrib.framework.assign_from_checkpoint_fn(
        checkpoint_path, module.variable_map)
    with tf.Session() as session:
      init_fn(session)
      module.export(export_path, session=session)
```

Fine points to note:

- `build_model_body()` should transform inputs to outputs (say, pixels to feature vectors) as suitable for a Hub module, but not include data reading, or loss and optimizers. For transfer learning, these are best left to the consumer of the module. Some refactoring may be required.
- Supplying the `module.variable_map` is essential, to translate from plain variable names as created by running `build_model_body()` by itself to the variable names created by instantiating the Module, live in scope `module/state`.